# Pandas - Select Dataframe rows based on column values to generate 1:1 relationship

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe, where I am trying to select rows based on the below logic.
I very new to pandas and I am having a hard time to generate my desired output.

For each group, I need to assign a Teacher to each student (1:1) relation if possible.
For Group1, we have only one teacher, so all 4 students get assigned to Teacher_1.
For Group2, we have 2 teachers Teacher_2 gets Student_5 and Teacher_3 gets Student_6 as Teacher_2 is already assigned to student_5.
For Group3, we have 2 Teachers but only one student, so Student_7 gets assigned to Teacher_5

I read about [DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas-dataframe-shift) and [Dataframe.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to work next/previous row values, but I am not sure how to use them for this case.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

[Current dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNr5X.jpg)

```
Group No.   Student Teacher Teacher_Score

1   Student_1   Teacher_1   5
1   Student_2   Teacher_1   5
1   Student_3   Teacher_1   5
1   Student_4   Teacher_1   5
2   Student_5   Teacher_2   4
2   Student_5   Teacher_3   3
2   Student_5   Teacher_4   3
2   Student_6   Teacher_2   4
2   Student_6   Teacher_3   3
2   Student_6   Teacher_4   3
3   Student_7   Teacher_5   5
3   Student_7   Teacher_6   4
```

Desired Output
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be6Y0.jpg)

```
Group No.   Student Teacher Teacher_Score

1   Student_1   Teacher_1   5
1   Student_2   Teacher_1   5
1   Student_3   Teacher_1   5
1   Student_4   Teacher_1   5
2   Student_5   Teacher_2   4
2   Student_6   Teacher_3   3
3   Student_7   Teacher_5   5
```

Comment: It is really hard to understand your logic. At the end, which teacher `student_7` would get is ambiguous, and so is in some cases in group 2

Comment: and if you have a group with 3 student and 2 teachers, which teacher is used twice?

Comment: I am using a logic to assign a score to each teacher. The teachers have been sorted in descending order. A teacher with a higher score gets priority and can be used again like in group3 Student_7 gets Teacher_5 as it has a higher score of 5 than Teacher_6 and in Group2 Student_5 gets Teacher_2 and then Student_6 gets Teacher_3 as per the order of the teachers.

Hope this helps!